# extending the width of a row in html

Tags: html, jinja2

This is the jinja2 template I am using to render the HTML page

```
<TABLE BORDER="5" WIDTH="100%" CELLPADDING="4" CELLSPACING="3">
<TR>
    <TH><H2>my_first_project</H2></TH>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TH>S.no</TH>
    <TH>Job Title</TH>
    <TH>Job Description</TH>
    <TH>Job Posted on</TH>
    <TH>Job Location</TH>
</TR>
{% for x in something %}
<TR ALIGN="CENTER">
    {% for i in x %}
    <TD>{{i}}</TD>
    {% endfor %}
</TR>
{% endfor %}
```

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhVrl.jpg)

Focussing on the HTML part, how can I make the first block(my_first_project) fill the full width of the table without altering the current view of the table shown in the image and 
why is **S.no column** is wider than it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add colspan attribute to th tag

```html
<TABLE BORDER="5" WIDTH="100%" CELLPADDING="4" CELLSPACING="3">
  <TR>
    <TH colspan="5">
      <H2>my_first_project</H2>
    </TH>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TH>S.no</TH>
    <TH>Job Title</TH>
    <TH>Job Description</TH>
    <TH>Job Posted on</TH>
    <TH>Job Location</TH>
  </TR>
  <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
    <TD>1</TD>
    <TD>Test</TD>
    <TD>Description</TD>
    <TD>Postedest</TD>
    <TD>Location</TD>
  </TR>
```